# why is the syntax for "condition" and "break" different in gdb?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I seem to be having an issue with gdb.  Let's say I create a conditional breakpoint in a loop over i with the command

```
 break file.cpp:line_no  if i==120
```

everything good, it creates breakpoint 3 and the code breaks when i==120.  Now I'm getting a problem at i==495, and I want to re-use the same breakpoint, so I use:

```
 condition 3 if i==495
```

Well, there I get a "syntax error in expression near `if i==495'  So I try:

```
condition 3 i==495
```

No more error, and the info for the breakpoint looks promising:

```
 3       breakpoint     keep y   <MULTIPLE>         
         stop only if i==495
```

But it doesn't stop at the breakpoint when the condition is reached.  So I start writing this question, and it occurs to me to try:

```
 condition 3 "if i == 495"
```

and hooray it works.  So I guess my questions are:  1.  Why the different syntax between the two commands?  and 2.  Why is the info so confusing?   The new info says 'if "if i==495"', but shouldn't that only evaluate to true if 'i==495' evaluates to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last try is not doing what you think it is doing.  When you write:

```
cond 3 "if i == 495"
```

the condition is actually the string constant "if i == 495", which is never false.  So, the breakpoint stops.

You can see this either by doing `print i` (for some hits it won't be 495), or by `cond 3 "anything goes here!"`.

The correct syntax was your second attempt:

```
cond 3 i == 495
```

I can't say why this isn't triggering for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gdb to debug fortran it might happen that you get a syntax error when trying the reasonable command:

```
(gdb) b foo.f:10 if i == 0
A syntax error in expression, near `= 0'.
```

The reason for this is that you must use the old-style fortran syntax (`.eq.` rather than `==` and so on) for logical operators:

```
(gdb) b foo.f:10 if i .eq. 0 
Breakpoint 1 at 0x432738: file foo.f, line 10.
```

Comment: I'm aware that this is not strictly related to the question, but this question is one of the top hits when searching for syntax errors when using conditional breakpoints in gdb, and the top hit that doesn't assume a language (as far as I could tell).